# jQuery Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am reading a chapter from PHP Ajax Cookbook. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
    <form class='simpleValidation'>
        <div class='fieldRow'>
            <label for='title'>Title *</label>
            <input type='text' id='title' name='title' class='required'>
        </div>
        <div class='fieldRow'>
            <label for='url'>URL</label>
            <input type='text' id='url' name='url' value='http://'>
        </div>
        <div class='fieldRow'>
            <label for='labels'>Labels</label>
            <input type='text' id='labels' name='labels'>
        </div>
        <div class='fieldRow'>
            <label for='textarea'>Text *</label>
            <textarea id='textarea' class='required'></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class='fieldRow'>
            <input type='submit' id='formSubmitter' value='Submit'>
        </div>
    </form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
        var timerId  = 0;

        $('.required').keyup(function() {
            clearTimeout(timerId);

            timerId = setTimeout(function() {
                ajaxValidation($(this));
            }, 200);
        });
    });

    var ajaxValidation = function (object) {
            var $this   = $(object);
            var param   = $this.attr('name');
            var value   = $this.val();

            $.get(
                'inputValidation.php',
                {'param' : param, 'value' : value },
                function (data) {
                    if (data.status == 'OK') {
                        validateRequiredInputs();
                    } else {
                        $this.addClass('failed');
                    }
                },
                'json'
            );

            var validateRequiredInputs = function() {
                var numberOfMissingInputs = 0;

                $('.required').each(function(i) {
                    var $item = $(this);
                    var itemValue = $item.val();

                    if (itemValue.length) {
                        $item.removeClass('failed');
                    } else {
                        $item.addClass('failed');
                        numberOfMissingInputs++;
                    }
                });

                var $submitButton = $('#formSubmitter');

                if (numberOfMissingInputs > 0) {
                    $submitButton.prop('disabled', true)
                } else {
                    $submitButton.prop('disabled', false)
                }
            }
        }
```

PHP (inputValidation.php):

```
<?php
$result = array();

if (isset($_GET['param'])) {
    $result['status'] = 'OK';
    $result['message'] = 'Input is valid!';
} else {
    $result['status'] = 'ERROR';
    $result['message'] = 'Input IS NOT valid';
}

echo json_encode($result)
?>
```

When I start typing in the `Title *` field I get the following error from the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

Note: I am using jQuery 2.2.1

So far I have checked the code for mis-spelling but cannot find any.

Comment: Are you sure you have no other script on same page?

Comment: Yes sir, nothing running in the background or anything.

Comment: there is no toLowerCase anywhere in your code?

Comment: You call the validation with `ajaxValidation($(this))`, than in function again `var $this   = $(object);` -> change to `var $this = object;`

Comment: @JordanHendrix the `toLowerCase` is an internal jQuery function.

Comment: You make a request after each key stroke? Anyway, post a link where we can reproduce the problem. @RobertRocha, no, it is not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `this` bit in `ajaxValidation($(this))` isn't what you think it is: [it's actually `window`, since it's being called by `setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#The_this_problem).

One solution is to assign `$(this)` to a variable *outside* the function, like so:

```
$('.required').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    var $this = $(this);

    timerId = setTimeout(function() {
        ajaxValidation($this);
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: Ha! Thanks. it would have taken me forever to debug that one!