# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined when passing data from one method to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have the following code that is part of a Jquery plugin:

```
    var Model = {

    loadData: function() {

        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
                url: 'some.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                //contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {'quality' : 'quality'},
                success: (function(data) {
                    self.toggleButton(data);             
                })
        });

    },

    toggleButton: function(data) {
            /*
            if the checkbox is ticked, alert the data from the ajax call
            */
            // the data can be displayed here
            console.log(data);
            if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
                alert(data);            
            } else {
                Do something else...;
            }
    },


};
```

When I load the page I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
at Array.checked (jquery.min.js:2)
at jquery.min.js:2
at o (jquery.min.js:2)
at vt (jquery.min.js:2)
at vt (jquery.min.js:2)
at nt (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.nt.matchesSelector (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.filter (jquery.min.js:2)
at init.is (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.toggleButton (....)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when user ticks the checkbox, the data to be alerted. I know the data is being passed successfully since I can see it in the console.log statement in the toggleButton method. But when I tick the checkbox I get the following message in the console: I

```
v.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 563856.225, jQuery183032448186288432224: true, …}
```

In the toggleButton method, the $(this) selector refers to the checkbox element whereas the data parameter is a JSON object.

So what is the best way to access data once the checkbox is ticked? Any help on this is greatly appreciated as I'm not sure how to move forward with this. Thank you

Comment: where's `toLowerCase` used in your code? I don't see it.

Comment: You are calling toLowerCase on an undefined object.

Comment: Essentially you're doing `jQuery(Model)` which is probably an invalid selector / collection. What is `$(this)` supposed to be?

Comment: Please help clarify your question by addressing the above comments with an [edit] to address the concerns. As is, your question is not likely to have a sufficient answer without more information.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I have clarified my question by addressing the comments. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: @TheEmperor if you notice ExplosionPills' comment, the `$(this).is(':checked')` is most likely the issue, since `this` refers to `Model` in that context, and not an actual `HTMLElement`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I believe you are right. The $(this) refers to the checkbox element. So basically when it is checked I want the data to be alerted. I'm assuming this is a problem associated with the this keyword and data binding but I'm not sure how to rectify it.

Comment: Which checkbox element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877731/jquery-cannot-read-property-tolowercase-of-undefined) (in fact I'm convinced of it)

Comment: Log `this` inside `toggleButton` just after you log `data` to see what it is. What version of jQuery are you using?